# Command to copy from a file

Tags: command-line

Lets suppose that I have a file named "foo". For example, I can copy its contend doing:

```
gedit foo
ctrl+a ctrl+c
alt+f4
```

But, I wonder if I can do the same thing with something like:

```
COMMAND foo
```

Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you can try to copy ( append) the contents of file foo using command redirection.

```
#cat foo > new.txt  --> this will copy the contents of file foo to new.txt
#cat foo >> new1.txt --> this will append the contents of file foo to new1.txt
```

If your intention is not copying to other file and is just copying in to buffer/clipboard then try ***"xclip"***

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to copy the file:

`cp /path/to/file/filename.extension /path/to/other/file/(new)filename.extention(2)`

Don't change the extension if you want to keep the file type.